# Mapping Spark dataframe columns with special characters

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following schema after executing df.printSchema()

```
root
 |-- key:col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key:col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col5: string (nullable = true)
```

I need to access the key:col2 using the column name but the following line gives an error due to the : within the name

```
df.map(lambda row:row.key:col2)
```

I have tried

```
df.map(lambda row:row["key:col2"])
```

I can easily obtain values from col3, col4 and col5 using

```
df.map(lambda row:row.col4).take(10)
```

Comment: Does `getattr` work?  `lambda row: getattr(row, 'key:col2')`?

Comment: Bracket notation (`row["key:col2"]`) works just fine. You can also convert it to a `dictionary`:  `row.asDict().get("key:col1")`. @mgilson [Yes it does](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/types.py#L1405-L1429).

Comment: @mgilson Thanks, lambda row: getattr(row, 'key:col2') works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can probably use `getattr`:

```
df.map(lambda row: getattr(row, 'key:col2'))
```

I'm not an expert in `pyspark`, so I don't know if this is the *best* way or not :-).

You *might* also be able to use `operator.attrgetter`:

```
from operator import attrgetter
df.map(attrgetter('key:col2'))
```

IIRC, it performs *slightly* better than `lambda` in some situations.  This is probably more pronounced in this case than usual because it can avoid the global `getattr` name lookup,  and in this case, I think it looks a bit nicer too.